# While using KUDU Client API to create table, how do I set an order of columns ion the Primary Key?

Tags: api, create-table, composite-primary-key, apache-kudu

I'm trying to write code that transfers some tables from SQL Server to KUDU using JAVA KuduClient API. On SQL I got a table that has composite Primary Key (for example: PRIMARY KEY ([ID], [DATA_SOURCE])).
How do I guarantee that on KUDU the Primary Key columns will be in same order?

```
ArrayList<ColumnSchema> columns = new ArrayList<>(1);
columns.add(new ColumnSchema.ColumnSchemaBuilder("DATA_SOURCE", 
    Type.STRING).nullable(false).key(true).build());
columns.add(new ColumnSchema.ColumnSchemaBuilder("DB_USER", 
    Type.STRING).nullable(false).build());
columns.add(new ColumnSchema.ColumnSchemaBuilder("ID", 
    Type.INT32).nullable(false).key(true).build());
Schema schema = new Schema(columns);
CreateTableOptions createOptions = new CreateTableOptions()
client.createTable(tableName, schema, createOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ususally the columns are created in the same order they are specified in `ArrayList<ColumnSchema> columns`.

However there are some [limitations to schema design](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/kudu_limitations.html) in Kudu.

> The columns which make up the primary key must be listed first in the schema.

This limitation is not present in SQL server. Hence you might be forced to use different column order from the one used in SQL Server.

P.S: May I ask why do you need the column order to be the same as SQL Server?